Integrate Next.js to an existing Flask project
Actually, we have an app in Flask (for back) and with a template engine (for front) and I'm looking for how to integrate Next.js into it (Next will replace the template engine and Flask continue to ensure the back-end).
The few articles I've read on the subject always explain the same way of doing it.
Vercel for instance, say to first create a next.js app, then install Flask and then create a Flask app in the /app/ directory.
So if I understand, it is not possible to keep the current Flask app and integrate Next.js.
Is that right ? and how do you explain it technically ?
Thanks

Have you tried just moving your Flask code into app/? What happened?

No, because I thought keep architecture of project as it currently stands. (sorry for late response)

I believe this should be technically possible (perhaps depending on the architecture of your current Flask app). You will have to relatively move the flask app into your Next.js project.
The structure should look like as follows (with the App router):
~/
├── app/
├── ├── ...
├── api/ <-- Flask routes
├── vercel.json <-- Important for production
├── next.config.mjs
├── requirements.txt
├── ...


Note: If using the src/ directory, the Python api/ directory should be in there. It just needs to be outside of app/.


Configuration & rewrites
next.config.mjs

Add a rewrite to your Flask app:

rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
            ? 'http://127.0.0.1:5328/api/:path*'
            : '/api/',
      },
    ]
  } // this will rewrite any api request to the flask app

vercel.json (Production)
If your main Python file is, for instance, index.py, your vercel.json should look like:
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/api/index"
        }
    ]
}


Final notes

Your requirements.txt should be in the root of the project.
Run the Flask app in the main python file:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(load_dotenv=True)


Again, I don't know how your Flask app is set up already, but this is how I integrated it myself. You shouldn't need a venv or anything like that, as this set up should handle everything for you.
Here is a link to a repository where I did this a bit ago: https://github.com/clxrityy/next-spotify-stats
